# Increase animation speed in Cosmic Cuttlefish

Tags: gnome-shell, 18.10, effects, animations

Is it possible to increase animation speed for window transitions in Cosmic Cuttlefish?

**Edit**: Is it possible to set a maximum duration for the transition effects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [**Impatience**](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/277/impatience/) extension for GNOME shell to increase the *overall* GNOME shell animation speed.

[image]

Refer to this to learn more about installing and configuring GNOME extensions: [How do I install and manage GNOME Shell extensions?](https://askubuntu.com/q/75530)

Comment: Thank you. That is useful. Is it possible to set a maximum duration for the transition effects?

Comment: @JoyceBabu I'm not aware of any way, sorry :(